# setState called everytime I type something in input

Tags: reactjs

so i'm facing an issue where whenever I write something in input, handleCommentAdded is called which calls setState, re-rendering everything. This makes everything that is typed or was typed in the input to appear as comments and i want what is in the input when I click submit to appear as comment. How can I fix this?

```
 class WriteComments extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
         commentAdded:"",
       }
      this.handleButton = this.handleButton.bind(this);
      this.handleCommentAdded = this.handleCommentAdded.bind(this);
  }

  handleCommentAdded(event) {
    this.setState({newComment: event.target.value});
  }

  handleButton() {
    return(
       <div>
       {comment}
       </div>
   )
 }


render() {
  return(
<div>
 <input type="text" value={this.state.commentAdded} onChange=  
   {this.handleCommentAdded}/>

 <div className="button">
    <button
        type="button"
        onClick={e => this.handleButton(e)}
     >
     Write
    </button>
  </div>
```

)
   }
   }

Comment: Please check your state you are try to setstate newComment and you does not define inside constructor please make single state every whare like text field constructor and setstate as well it will work.

Comment: Hi jennielisajane, I just submitted an answer that might better explain what you're trying to acheive. Let me know if that works for you. I'll also write some comments for you in the sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is calling `handleCommentAdded` on `onChange`
set state in `handleButton`

```js
class WriteComments extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      commentAdded: ""
    };
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    this.handleButton = this.handleButton.bind(this);
  }

  handleButton() {
    this.setState({ commentAdded: this.inputRef.current.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref={this.inputRef} />

        <div className="button">
          {this.state.commentAdded !== "" ? (
            <div>{this.state.commentAdded}</div>
          ) : (
            <button type="button" onClick={e => this.handleButton(e)}>
              Write
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<WriteComments />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Comment: hi so what should i do if i have to do something important after doing this.setstate(commentadded) in handleButton()? I added some code in handlebutton after the setting state part and that part isn't being called because this.setstate rerenders and i have to submit something again to trigger handleButton

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo where textfield value can be get by button click. Component will render everytime when setState calls. Hope it can help you!

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  state ={ inputValue:"" };
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  handleChange=(e)=>{
   this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  }
  
  handleSubmit=()=>{
    console.log("inputValue::", this.state.inputValue);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```